# Debugging the context of a Package

Tags: packages, neural-networks

I am working on a package of functions that complement the `` NeuralNetworks` `` package that Wolfram provides.  I am having a problem with the following code, which is essentially a wrapper for two commands that I run frequently:

```
runNetwork[data_,desc_,dlist_,{tlist_,vlist_}]:= Module[{fdfwd,m,r},
    fdfwd = InitializeRBFNet[
            desc[[tlist,dlist]],
            data[[tlist]],
            1,RandomInitialization->False];
    {m,r} = NeuralFit[fdfwd,
        desc[[tlist,dlist]],
        data[[tlist]],
        desc[[vlist,dlist]],
        data[[vlist]],
        100,Method->SteepestDescent,CriterionPlot->False];
    {m,r}]
```

When I declare this function within my notebook, it runs as expected; however if I place it in a package (for instance, `` MyNeuralNetworks` ``) then I get errors of the following type:

> Set::shape: "Lists {SolarNeuralNetwork`Private`m\$2436,SolarNeuralNetwork`Private`r\$2436} 
>   and SolarNeuralNetwork`Private`NeuralFit[<<1>>] are not the same shape."

which suggests to me that the list `fdfwd`  that is returned by the first function is not being passed correctly to the second function.  I have tried adding a `` Needs["NeuralNetworks`"] `` line in both the Public and Private portions of the package as well as in the `BeginPackage` line following [this question and answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/).  I'm new to package writing, so there may be something obvious I'm missing.  It's possible that the answer I'm looking for is [hidden somewhere in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744624/) but I don't know how to implement those suggestions in my context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this question may be of use to future visitors.  I had assumed that using

```
Needs["NeuralNetworks`"]
```

or

```
BeginPackage["MyNeuralNetworks`",{"NeuralNetworks`"}]
```

was sufficient to establish the `$ContextPath` for my package; however when I loaded the neural networks package into a notebook, I noticed:

```
$ContextPath
{"NeuralNetworks`VQ`", "NeuralNetworks`UnsupervisedNet`", "NeuralNetworks`Perceptron`",
   "NeuralNetworks`NeuralFit`", "NeuralNetworks`Hopfield`",
   "NeuralNetworks`FeedForwardRBFNet`", "NeuralNetworks`DynamicNet`", 
    "NeuralNetworks`Common`", "NeuralNetworks`CommonCBV`", "NeuralNetworks`", ...}
```

I wrongfully thought that `Need`ing `` NeuralNetworks` `` would automatically include the rest of the needed packages into my context.  Explicitly including all of the neural network packages in my custom package did the trick:

```
BeginPackage["MyNeuralNetwork`",{"NeuralNetworks`VQ`", "NeuralNetworks`UnsupervisedNet`", 
   "NeuralNetworks`Perceptron`", "NeuralNetworks`NeuralFit`",
   "NeuralNetworks`Hopfield`", "NeuralNetworks`FeedForwardRBFNet`",
   "NeuralNetworks`DynamicNet`", "NeuralNetworks`Common`",
   "NeuralNetworks`CommonCBV`", "NeuralNetworks`"}]
```