# Wolfram Workbench autocompletition

Tags: workbench

Suppose I have some project in `Wolfram Workbench`. In some packages need DatabaseLink`. I write it in this way:

```
BeginPackage["test`"]
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

test::usage="";

Begin["`Private`"]

test[x_]:=SQLConnections[];

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

All work fine. But autocompletion of DatabaseLink functions don't work. How can I use autocompletion for imported contexts (applications)?

Comment: Off-topic, but why you don't add the packages as in `BeginPackage["test`", {"DatabaseLink`"}]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks there is [difference](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-specifying-dependent-packages) between this two ways of import