# How do contexts work exactly? Is there anything special about Private` or Internal` context?

Tags: contexts

Suppose I begin a package:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
```

Before running this command in a fresh kernel, the context and path were:

```
$ContextPath->$Context
```

> {"System`", "Global`"} -> "Global`"

and afterward:

> {"MyPackage`", "System`"} -> "MyPackage`"

Now if I were to declare a function `Fun1`:

```
Fun1::"usage" = "Fun1[]";
```

The context of Fun1 is obviously `Context[Fun1]`:

> "MyPackage`"

Now if I begin a subcontext inside this context:

```
Begin["`Private`"];
```

Now my context and path are:

> {"MyPackage`", "System`"} -> "MyPackage`Private`"

Now if I try to define a new function with the same name `Fun1` here in the subcontext:

```
Fun1[arg_] := 1 + 1;
```

It gets defined in "MyPackage`" context whilst clearly the current context right now was
"MyPackage`Private`".

If I were to use a different name say `Fun2` here then it gets defined in the subcontext as expected:

```
Fun2[arg_] := 1 + 2;
```

Why is that? I am trying to understand the rules governing this. Does it mean if you are in a subcontext and there is a symbol with the same name existing in the outer context then the current context given by `$Context` is ignored if you define without using full context name?

```
MyPackage`Private`Fun1[arg_] := 1 + 3;
```

was the effect I was expecting. Is this rule general in terms of how deeply nested the current context is compared to where the symbol with the same name exists in the outer context?

---

I have a second question regarding `BeginPackage` second argument:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`",{"Package1`","Package2`"}]
```

is this the same as:

```
Needs["Package1`"];
Needs["Package2`"];
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
```

or

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];
Needs["Package1`"];
Needs["Package2`"];
```

Also are there any cases where in a multipackage paclet, these can produce different results, i.e. the order in which `Needs` are called relative to `BeginPackage` matters?

Also, does these do something different?

```
Needs["`MyPackage`"];
BeginPackage["`MyPackage`"];
```

Comment: How much does this topic addresses you question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/5478?

Comment: "Now if I try to define a new function with the same name Fun1 here in the subcontext:" But you didn't define a new function. You provided new DownValues for an existing symbol, i.e. a symbol that the evaluation engine already knows about and will find to exist in MyPackage context when it looks it up.

Comment: `$ContextPath` tells you where the evaluator will look for symbols. If you evaluate a symbol and that symbol isn't found in `$ContextPath`, then it will be "created" and "assigned" to the `$Context`. `Begin` changes the `$Context` but not the `$ContextPath`. `BeginPackage` changes both. `End` reset them back to what they were, and `EndPackage` resets them but also adds the just created context to `$ContextPath`.

Comment: And I don't think there is anything special about Private or Internal as part of the context name.

Comment: related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-ways-of-specifying-dependent-packages

Answer (score 1):

"BeginPackage" does 2 things. It defines a new context and it puts the new context on the ContextPath. "Begin" only defines a new context.

A new symbol is only defined if no symbol with this name is found.

Consider the following:

```
Remove["pack1`*"];
$ContextPath = {"System`"};

BeginPackage["pack1`"];
Print["in pack1"]
fun1[x_] = "fun1"; Print[fun1[x]];
Print["$ContextPath= ", $ContextPath];
Print["Symbols in context pack1:", Information["pack1`*"]];

Begin["`pack2`"];
Print["in pack2"];
fun1[x_] = "fun2"; Print[fun1[x]];
newVariable = 1;
Print["$ContextPath= ", $ContextPath];
Print["Symbols in context pack1`pack2:", Information["pack1`pack2`*"]];
End[]

Print["outside pack2: fun1[x]=", fun1[x]];
Print["$ContextPath= ", $ContextPath];
EndPackage[];
$ContextPath
```

with output:

[image]

As you can see, the second definition of "fun1" does not define a new symbol, it merely redefines the symbol in pack1. Only "newVAriable is defined in "pack1`pack2`"